# Linebreaking with \eqref and long tags

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, line-breaking

When using a long tag for an equation, is there a way to have an equivalent of `\eqref` that would allow LaTeX to break the reference between words, or even within words.

In the example below I get overfull `\hbox`. And when adding `\sloppy`, I will get huge spaces between words instead.

(As a bonus constraint, it should actually work with `\documentclass{llncs}`.)

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:inframetric}
d(x,y)\leq \rho \max(d(x,z),d(z,y))
\tag{$\rho$-inframetric inequality}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:triangle_inequality}
d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)
\tag{triangle inequality}
\end{equation}


\medskip

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, \eqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \eqref{eq:inframetric},     
\eqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \eqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \eqref{eq:inframetric},     
\eqref{eq:inframetric}

\medskip


$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3$
\eqref{eq:triangle_inequality},
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a command `\seqref` that mimics what `\eqref` does, without using a box; we have to use `refcount` to allow hyphenation also in the last word. I wouldn't redefine `\eqref`, because hyphenation of tags should not be used generally.

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,refcount}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\seqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@split{\getrefnumber{#1}}}}
\newcommand\tagform@split[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \m@th\normalfont(\ignorespaces #1\unskip\@@italiccorr)%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:inframetric}
d(x,y)\leq \rho \max(d(x,z),d(z,y))
\tag{$\rho$-inframetric inequality}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:triangle_inequality}
d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)
\tag{triangle inequality}
\end{equation}


\medskip

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:inframetric}

\medskip

\begingroup\itshape
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:inframetric}
\endgroup

\begin{thm}
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:triangle_inequality}, \seqref{eq:inframetric}, 
\seqref{eq:inframetric}
\end{thm}


$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3$
\seqref{eq:triangle_inequality},
\end{document}
```

Of course, bad line breaks are not automatically solved; they would be the same if you typed the tags directly.

[image]

Comment: i'd like to point out that any `\ref`, not just `\eqref`, has this problem.  (in this respect, `\eqref{xxx}` is equivalent to `(\ref{xxx})` with the addition of `\upshape`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, `\ref` doesn't box the reference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have `\normalfont` after `\begingroup`, so the behavior is exactly the same as `\eqref`'s.

Comment: @egreg -- agreed re boxing; i'll add that to the list of questions for `amsthm`, with thanks. however, a question: i tested, replacing `\eqref{...}` by `(\ref{...})` and "inequality" in the second paragraph doesn't hyphenate, although the patterns allow it as `in-equal-ity`; happens with `\seqref` as well as with `\ref`. overlong box warning shows `... (tri-an-gle inequality[])`. so something else is at work here. any idea what?

Comment: @barbarabeeton There must be something at the end of `\ref` that hinders hyphenating the last word. Using `\getrefnumber` instead of `\ref` seems to cure the problem.

Comment: @sunless Note that the code has been changed; now all words in the tag can be hyphenated, possibly reducing the bad breaks.

Comment: @egreg -- two more possibilities for improvement: `$\rho$-inframetric` can be made hyphenatable by using `\hyph` (defined as `\newcommand{\hyph}{-\penalty\z@\hskip\z@skip}`) instead of a typed hyphen.  and the long line in the last example is just a single math string; breaking at some of the commas (a better practice anyhow) would allow more places to adjust the line -- there's only one space in the original.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd leave the corrections to the usual methods at the final revision stage.

Comment: @egreg The default definition of `\ref` ends with a `\null` in `\@setref`. There must be a reason it was put there, but I can't find any explanation in `source2e.pdf`. Removing it, or manually adding `\hskip0pt` after "inequality" in the `\tag`, lets the word hyphenate.

Comment: @Dan My bet goes to “we don't want TeX to try hyphenating the material“.